# How do I conditionally render font awesome icons in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome, jsx

I am trying to conditionally render the empty and full heart icon from font awesome.

I am following a tutorial but they are using font awesome 4.7

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faHeart as faEmptyHeart } from "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons";
import { faHeart as faSolidHeart } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

//Input: liked: boolean
//Outpur: onClick

class Like extends Component {
  render() {
    let classes = { faSolidHeart };
    if (!this.props.liked) classes = { faEmptyHeart };
    return <FontAwesomeIcon icon={classes} />;
  }
}

export default Like;
```

Answer (score 3):

`icon` prop in `FontAwesomeIcon` does not expect an object, but an icon. What you are actually do is passing down an object with `key` equal to `faSolidHeart` and it's value as `faHeart` icon.

Just remove the curly brackets. A simplified and shortened solution below:

```
class Like extends Component {
  render() {
    return <FontAwesomeIcon icon={this.props.liked ? faSolidHeart : faEmptyHeart} />;
  }
}
```